# jQuery .on() method with multiple event handlers & multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-selectors

So I know that we can have multiple event handlers on the .on() method

```
$(document).on({
    'click': function (e) {
       // function
    },
    'hover': function (e) {
       // function    
    }
});
```

but is there anyway we can add multiple selectors to each event handler?

like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo, .foo', function () { 
     // function
});
```

but with multiple .on() methods:

```
$(document).on({
    'click', '#foo': function (e) {
       // doesn't work :(
    },
    'hover', '.foo': function (e) {
       // doesn't work :(    
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's not a valid object :)

Comment: so there isn't a way this can be done?

Comment: If you are having different selecters for each event, why not just split them out into their own `on` - it will be far more maintainable

Comment: use multiple `on()` methods or in case you need common selector then use selector as second argument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want different matching elements on different events, you need to use different `on` calls. You can use a single `on` call to hook multiple events for the *same* elements, but you can't use a single `on` for a mix and match of events and selectors (nor is there any need to).

---

You could, of course, create your *own* function that does that. For instance, something vaguely like:

```
$.fn.mixon = function(events) {
    Object.keys(events).forEach(function(selector) {
        var entry = events[selector];
        Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(event) {
            this.on(event, selector, entry[event]);
        }, this);
    }, this);
    return this;
};
```

...which you could use like this:

```
$(document).mixon({
    "#foo": {
        "click focus": function() {
           // ...
        }
    },
    ".foo": {
        click: function() {
           // ...
        }
    }
});
```